# Can't import a library that uses another library as module with Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, static-libraries

I have a library, let's call it android-sdk-mylibrary, that uses another library, android-sdk-mylibrary:mysublibrary, as a module.

I can build the project and I can create a local maven repository but the pom in the repo contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>android-sdk-mylibrary</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysublibrary</artifactId>
  <version>unspecified</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

even if in the `settings.gradle` I have:

```
include ':mysublibrary'
project(':mysublibrary').projectDir = new File('...path...')
```

and in the `build.gradle` I have:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':mysublibrary')
}
```

Then when I try to import the library in an app I get the error:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. Could not find
>   android-sdk-mylibrary:mysublibrary:unspecified.

How can I hide the sub-library in the maven repo and import only the implementation?

Do I have to import the sub-library as a maven repo?

Comment: u try for creating your own library ?

Comment: Yes, I have a library and now I'm wrapping that library into another one because I need to refactor the exposed APIs. So I want to import the code of the old library without exposing its classes. In this way I can then refactor the code

Comment: Not really clear why you are mixing Gradle and Maven projects

Comment: In the `settings.gradle`, you need to include the `mysublibrary` module

Comment: I did it. that's why I can add implementation project(path: ':mysublibrary')

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: thanks @MohammadAli

Comment: it is work for u @user6405527

Comment: @MohammadAli no it does not. It looks like I have to export the sublibrary in a maven repo and then use in the wrapping library